# How to register a backup application with the Win7 Action Center?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7

I've written a little application which continuously backs up my important files to Amazon S3.

I'd like to be able to inform windows that my application is running and thus the Windows Action Center doesn't need to bug the user about setting up a backup solution.

How can I do this using .Net? (VB by preference but any .Net is fine)

I've tagged with Win7 as I haven't endured Win8 yet - but if the solution is future-proof, it would be preferable.

Out of idle curiousity, Any information about doing the same for a firewall application would be appreciated (I assume it's similar).